# Porque a resposta do delete está vindo vazio? - CRUD Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

A função funciona deletando pelo um id informado, porém o livro não é deletado do banco de dados. Acabei fazendo uns testes e a resposta da função delete está vindo vazia
[Após acionar a função de delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o12rE.png),[Resposta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgzJ7.png)

Função de delete

```
export class DeleteLivroComponent implements OnInit{

  form: FormGroup;
  id: any;
  request: LivroDelete;
  categoriaList: string[] = ['Ficção', 'Fantasia', 'Romance', 'Terror', 'Drama', 'Sci-fi'];


  constructor(private livroService: LivroService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private fb:FormBuilder){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form=this.fb.group({
    id:['',Validators.required],
    nome:['',Validators.required],
    categoria:['',Validators.required]
  })
}
delete(){
  let livro:LivroDelete={id:this.form.controls['id'].value}
  console.log("teste");
  console.log(livro);
  this.livroService.deleteLivro(this.id, livro).subscribe(res =>{
  console.log(livro.id);
  console.log(res);
});
}
```

}

ConsoleLogos da função:
{id: '1'},
1,
{}

Função delete na API

```
app.delete('/livro', async function(req, res){
console.log("livro");
console.log(req.body.id);
let livro = await deleteLivro(req.body.id);
res.json({livro});
res.json(req.body.id);
console.log(req.body)
```

});

ConsoleLogs da API:
livro,
undefined,
{}

res.json({livro}): está vazio{}

Comment: Não ficou claro qual o problema

Comment: Já atualizei, mas o problema é que a resposta está vindo vazia